# Android - If statement gets ignored and bypassed

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am calling a PHP script from a function like this:

```
public static String XSSignUp(String username, String password, String email, String signInWith) {
      // Paramenters
      Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
      params.put(USERS_USERNAME, username);
      params.put(USERS_PASSWORD, password);
      params.put(USERS_EMAIL, email);
      params.put("signInWith", signInWith);
      params.put(USERS_IOS_DEVICE_TOKEN, IOS_DEVICE_TOKEN);
      params.put(USERS_ANDROID_DEVICE_TOKEN, ANDROID_DEVICE_TOKEN);

      StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
      for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
         if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
         try { postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
         } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
         postData.append('=');
         try { postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
         } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      }
      byte[] postDataBytes;
      postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
      StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
      try {
         URL url;
         url = new URL(TABLES_PATH + "m-signup.php?");
         HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
         conn.setConnectTimeout(20000);
         conn.setReadTimeout(20000);
         conn.setDoInput(true);
         conn.setDoOutput(true);
         conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

         // Get response
         if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream responseStream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));
            String line = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) { stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n"); }
            responseStreamReader.close();
            String response = stringBuilder.toString();
            responseStream.close();
            conn.disconnect();


            Log.i(TAG, "XSSignUp -> RESPONSE: " + response + "\n-----------------\n");

            if (response.equals("e_101")) { return E_101;
            } else if (response.equals("e_102")) { return E_102;
            } else {  return response; }


         // error
         } else { return "Something went wrong. Try again."; }
      } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); return e.getMessage(); }
   }
```

This is how I call that function:

```
 final String sup = XSSignUp(usernameTxt.getText().toString(), passwordTxt.getText().toString(), emailTxt.getText().toString(), "");
 Log.i(TAG, "SUP: " + sup);

 // errors
 if (sup.matches("e_101")) {
     hideHUD();
     simpleAlert(E_101, ctx);
 } else if (sup.matches("e_102")) {
     hideHUD();
     simpleAlert(E_102, ctx);
 } else { 
    Log.i(TAG, "YES, SIGN UP!");
 }
```

So, if I run my app and fill a signup form using **johndoe** as username, my PHP script returns a response string as "`e_101`" (username already exists), and it prevents the script to add records to my database. I get this message in the Logcat:

```
I/log-: XSSignUp -> RESPONSE: e_101
I/log-: SUP: e_101
I/log-: YES, SIGN UP!
```

Which is wrong, because I shouldn't get the last line: `I/log-: YES, SIGN UP!`. 
This compromises my app because instead of firing an alert dialog (`simpleAlert(E_101, ctx);`), it goes on and skips that part.

I don't really understand why the IF statement doesn't work, because I've also tried to do this:

```
final String sup = XSSignUp(usernameTxt.getText().toString(), passwordTxt.getText().toString(), emailTxt.getText().toString(), "");

sup = "e_101"; <-- FORCING THE sup STRING TO BE "e_101"!

// errors
if (sup.matches("e_101")) {
    hideHUD();
    simpleAlert(E_101, ctx);
} else if (sup.matches("e_102")) {
    hideHUD();
    simpleAlert(E_102, ctx);
} else { 
    Log.i(TAG, "YES, SIGN UP!");
}
```

and then it works! But it doesn't make any sense to me since the `sup` string is the same as the one that my function returns from the PHP script, as you can see by the Logcat messages...

I've also tried using equals():

```
sup.equals("e_101")
```

No positive result, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `sup.equalsIgnoreCase("e_101")`

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I've tried, but I've got the same result :(

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `response` contains extra new line `\n`, that's why `if` not work.

The problem is in here:

```
stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
```

Try to change it like below:

```
int i = 0;
while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
    if(i != 0)
        stringBuilder.append("\n");

    stringBuilder.append(line);

    i++;
}
```

**Or**

```
....

stringBuilder.replace(stringBuilder.lastIndexOf("\n"), stringBuilder.length(),"");
String response = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Beside this as you change the CASE of your `response` to upper inside `XSSignUp` and compare with lower CASE outside, you have to use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals` like

```
sup.equalsIgnoreCase("e_101")
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that line break was the issue, I couldn't really figure it out.